# Java SE-8 injecting class with JNI DefineClass resulting in NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm developing an application where I directly inject some classes into the JVM in the following way in a custom launcher:

Step 1: Load the jvm dll with LoadLibrary (C++ code)

Step 2: actually injecting the class: (note this uses the boot classloader)

```
jclass ljcl_LoadedClass = env->DefineClass(className, NULL, classBytes, classSize);
```

Step 3: Launch the application
`jniEnvironment_->CallStaticVoidMethod` to actually call the main method and start the application.

Later on in the Java code, I try to use the injected class

```
mySingleton = MySingletonClass.getInstance();
```

This line results in a NoClassDefFound exception, which I'm having a hard time to solve.
Note that the same code is working with Java SE-7, so it likely is due to some changes on how either classes are garbage collected or due to changes in visibility to the classloader - I'm just stuck on how to debug this and find the reason.

Another interesting thing is that within the C++ code (before starting the application, but with the JVM dll loaded, the follwoing code actually finds the class and I'm even able to call the getInstance method:

```
jclass olDecryptorClass = jniEnvironment_->FindClass("com/foo/bar/MySingletonClass");
```

Answer (score 2):

I know Andrea and have discovered the cause, and a solution, but do not know why this change has occurred in Java 8.

I key piece of information was missing in the original question that a Java agent is used, and the class causing the `NoClassDefFoundError` is used by the agent.

I created a very simple C++ console application to launch the JVM, a simple Agent which outputs to the console "Agent Started" when the `premain()` method is called, and then "Loading class: className" by our overriding `ClassFileTransformer.transform()` method.

When using Java 7, we get the following as we debug:

C++ step

```
options[1].optionString = "-javaagent:simple-agent.jar";
errorCode = createJavaVM(&javaVM, (void**)&jniEnv, &initArgs);
```

Console

```
Agent Started
```

C++ step

```
jclass ljcl_LoadedClass = jniEnv->DefineClass(CLASS_NAME, NULL, ljby_ClassBytes, lji_Size);
```

Console

```
Loading class: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
```

C++ step

```
jniEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(helloWorldClass, mainMethod, mainArgs);
```

Console

```
Loading class: com/for/bar/HelloWorld
Hello World!
```

In Java 8, this changes to:

C++ step

```
options[1].optionString = "-javaagent:simple-agent.jar";
errorCode = createJavaVM(&javaVM, (void**)&jniEnv, &initArgs);
```

Console

```
Agent Started
Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
... 8 more
Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl$1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 5 more
Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl$2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 5 more
Loading class: java/util/function/Function
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 5 more
Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl$3
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 5 more
Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleImpl$4
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 5 more
Loading class: java/lang/ClassValue
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 5 more
Loading class: java/lang/ClassValue$Entry
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 6 more
Loading class: java/lang/ClassValue$Identity
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 7 more
Loading class: java/lang/ClassValue$Version
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 7 more
Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MemberName$Factory
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 5 more
Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleStatics
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 4 more
Loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleStatics$1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 5 more
Loading class: sun/misc/PostVMInitHook
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
... 3 more
```

C++ step

```
jclass ljcl_LoadedClass = jniEnv->DefineClass(CLASS_NAME, NULL, ljby_ClassBytes, lji_Size);
```

Console

```
Loading class: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
```

C++ step

```
jniEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(helloWorldClass, mainMethod, mainArgs);
```

Console

```
Loading class: com/objectiflune/simple/TestClass
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass
at com.foo.bar.ClassTransformer.transform(ClassTransformer.java:41)
at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
... 13 more
Hello World!
```

It's easy to see why the initial 14 `java/lang` classes fail to find our JVMDefinedClass, it hasn't been defined yet. But even after we have defined it, there appears to be some knock on effect which causes the rest of the application to not find the class.

The solution therefore is to make sure our `ClassFileTransformer.transform()` method ignores these (and any), Java system classes:

```
@Override
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
    ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

    if (className.equals("com/foo/bar/JVMDefinedClass")
     || className.startsWith("com/sun")
     || className.startsWith("java/")
     || className.startsWith("javax/")
     || className.startsWith("org/ietf")
     || className.startsWith("org/jcp")
     || className.startsWith("org/omg")
     || className.startsWith("org/w3c")
     || className.startsWith("org/xml")
     || className.startsWith("sun/")
     || className.startsWith("com/oracle/")
     || className.startsWith("jdk/")
     || className.startsWith("oracle/")
     || className.startsWith("javafx/")
    ) return null;
//... rest of method ...//
```

Now that we don't process those 14 classes, no `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown and the application runs as expected.

Thing only thing I don't understand is why the JVM in Java 8 now sends these 14 classes through the agent when it didn't before, and whether this is supposed to happen.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: Hi, thought this might have come under the banner of:
Have the same problem?

Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem?
Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. From :How do I write a good answer?